# Image display issue in datagridview from imagepath stored in database(sqlite) in windows form(C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, datagridview

I am working C# desktop application with sqlite. Store Image path properly as

like `C:\Users\USER\Pictures\pms_1484911839.45213251.jpg`.

And I want to display the images in datagridview. My Code

```
private void loadTable(){
conn.Open();
SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM products", conn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
foodListView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
foodListView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
foodListView.RowHeadersVisible = false;
foodListView.DataSource = dt;

DataGridViewImageColumn imageColumn = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
Image img;
int i = 0;
imageColumn.HeaderText = "Image";
imageColumn.Name = "image";
foodListView.Columns.Insert(3, imageColumn);

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    img = Image.FromFile(@dr["image"].ToString());
    foodListView.Rows[i].Cells["image"].Value = img;
    i++;
}

conn.Close();}
```

My Output is like

[image]

Where is my problem. Thank you.

Comment: When you debug, what is the value of `@dr["image"].ToString()` for any given record which isn't being displayed properly?  What is the resulting `img`?  I'd also recommend declaring the `img` variable *inside* the loop so you're not potentially over-writing all previous images with each iteration of the loop.  It's possible that only the *last* image is broken, but is also overwriting the rest of them.

Comment: When I debug I got `C:\Users\USER\Pictures\pms_1484911839.45213251.jpg` which is exists. I also declare `img` inside the loop. No change happen.

Comment: is the image saved as the path only in the database ?

Comment: @IftakharulAlam , cheers for being from my country :)

Comment: Yes. Like exactly same as `C:\Users\USER\Pictures\pms_1484911839.45213251.jpg`

Comment: The code should work just fine. Adding a if(File.Exist(path)).. is always  a good idea.

Comment: @IftakharulAlam , it makes no sense , you are binding the datagridview to the datatable first and then looping through the datatable to add images to the datagridview ! why ?!!!

Comment: @zack: The dbms contains the paths and the imagecolumn is added after binding. This is quite normal!

Comment: @TaW,yes , but isn't it unnecessary ! ... either you create an image column in design view and bind your datatable to the dgv or you just loop through the datatable to add both the text(column 1) and the image at the same time

Comment: Try detaching your Bitmaps from GDI+ and avoid overriding it while looping. Something like:  `Bitmap img = new Bitmap(@dr["image"].ToString());  foodListView["image", i].Value = new Bitmap(img);`. A `File.Exits()` check beforehand won't hurt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
//{
//    img = Image.FromFile(@dr["image"].ToString());
//    foodListView.Rows[i].Cells["image"].Value = img;
//    i++;
//}
foodListView.CellFormatting += foodListView_CellFormatting;



 private void foodListView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (foodListView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "image")
        {
            e.Value = Bitmap.FromFile(e.Value.ToString());
            e.FormattingApplied = true;
        }
    }
```

try to apply cellformatting. make sure column is mapped with respective field.

Comment: `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

System.Windows.Forms.ConvertEventArgs.Value.get returned null.` on line `e.Value = Bitmap.FromFile(e.Value.ToString());`

Comment: imageColumn.DataPropertyName = "image"; you have to mapp the colum first

Comment: Working. Thank you. I think this is more optimize solution.

Comment: But If I recall  the function again it shows error `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'System.Drawing.Bitmap'
` in the line `e.Value = Bitmap.FromFile(e.Value.ToString());`. Any Idea why?

Comment: @IftakharulAlam check the file path.  also foodListView.CellFormatting -= foodListView_CellFormatting; unsubscribe event before subscribe it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load image from a a file into the `DataGridView`(in your case the path of the file is in the database) , then here's a sample code :

```
  Bitmap img;
  img = new Bitmap(dr[3].ToString); ////change column index as required
  DataGridViewImageColumn imageColumn = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
  ////other codes here 
  dgv.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value = img;
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Here i am simply using the `Bitmap` class ... and the op's code makes very less sense as he's,on the first hand,binding the datagridview to the datatable and then again looping through the datatable to add images to the dgv..i wonder why he didn't choose to do it all in one way

Comment: this will not make any difference at all. The images are not in the dbms, so he needs to fill in the images after binding.

Comment: @zackraiyan your solution isn't working. It says In valid parameter in `img = new Bitmap(dr[3].ToString())`

Comment: What will be the correct format? That's what I want to know.

Comment: Do u really wanna go with a datatable first ? and iterate over it twice ? there are better solutions available :)

Comment: if i were you,either i would go with a datareader,create a class to handle a data and create a `List` of it,then iterate over it or i'll just use the datatable once ... :)

Comment: OH ! and don't forget to enable `doubleBuffering` for the dgvw :) That'll help to improve the performance :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the code in the above working absolutely fine. But the problem was I call `loadTable()` before the form loaded. That's why the function creates image dispay issue. When I call the function after the form load images load properly. Thank you everyone.

[image]